# How to use current date in a sql query of Db2

Tags: java, sql, db2

I need a query to insert current date in a sql query. Below query works when in my DB2.

```
select * from H1TI1.PS_CAL_DETP_TBL  where END_DT='2000-02-25' with ur;
```

I need to put current date as following  `END_DT = CURRENT_DATE` .

And also want to use `COUNT` function to count how many rows i get as a result.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: And did you try execute your query with `current_date` as shown by yourself?

Comment: use `WHERE END_DT = CURRENT DATE`. `CURRENT DATE` will get you the current date.  It is built into DB2.

Answer (score 2):

```
select Count(*) from H1TI1.PS_CAL_DETP_TBL  where END_DT = CURRENT DATE with ur;
```

Count will count all the rows where END_DT is equal to Current Date(DB2 has this as a built in function).